# How do I tag the lowest-level units within an organization structure (represented by several LEVEL_ID columns)?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that lists different sectors of a government at various sub-sector levels. It looks like this:

```
LEVEL1ID   LEVEL2ID   LEVEL3ID   LEVEL4ID   LEVEL5ID   YEAR   DESCRIP_E
0          0          0          0          0          2019   Government of X
5          0          0          0          0          2019   Department of Oceans
5          200        0          0          0          2019   Coast Guard
5          200        300        0          0          2019   Coast Guard HQ
5          200        300        400        0          2019   CG HQ - Business Mgmt
5          200        300        401        0          2019   CG HQ - IT
5          200        300        402        0          2019   CG HQ - Vessels
5          200        301        0          0          2019   CG Training
5          200        301        405        0          2019   CG Training - Employees
5          200        301        406        0          2019   CG Training - Students
5          200        302        0          0          2019   CG North
5          200        303        0          0          2019   CG East
5          200        303        407        0          2019   CG East - Shore-Based Personnel
5          200        303        407        500        2019   CG East - Business Mgmt
5          200        303        407        501        2019   CG East - Operations
0          0          0          0          0          2018   Government of X
5          0          0          0          0          2018   Department of Oceans
5          200        0          0          0          2018   Coast Guard
5          200        300        0          0          2018   Coast Guard HQ
5          200        300        400        0          2018   CG HQ - Business Mgmt
(and so on)
```

I want to create a new binary variable that tags rows that represent the lowest-level organizational units within a given year. That is, I want my dataset to look like this:

```
LEVEL1ID   LEVEL2ID   LEVEL3ID   LEVEL4ID   LEVEL5ID   YEAR   UNIQUE     DESCRIP_E
0          0          0          0          0          2019   No         Government of X
5          0          0          0          0          2019   No         Department of Oceans
5          200        0          0          0          2019   No         Coast Guard
5          200        300        0          0          2019   No         Coast Guard HQ
5          200        300        400        0          2019   Yes        CG HQ - Business Mgmt
5          200        300        401        0          2019   Yes        CG HQ - IT
5          200        300        402        0          2019   Yes        CG HQ - Vessels
5          200        301        0          0          2019   No         CG Training
5          200        301        405        0          2019   Yes        CG Training - Employees
5          200        301        406        0          2019   Yes        CG Training - Students
5          200        302        0          0          2019   Yes        CG North
5          200        303        0          0          2019   No         CG East
5          200        303        407        0          2019   No         CG East - Shore-Based Personnel
5          200        303        407        500        2019   Yes        CG East - Business Mgmt
5          200        303        407        501        2019   Yes        CG East - Operations
0          0          0          0          0          2018   No         Government of X
5          0          0          0          0          2018   No         Department of Oceans
5          200        0          0          0          2018   No         Coast Guard
5          200        300        0          0          2018   No         Coast Guard HQ
5          200        300        400        0          2018   Yes        CG HQ - Business Mgmt
(and so on)
```

How could I do this in R (or Excel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
is_unique = function(x) !duplicated(x) & !duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)

df$UNIQUE = with(df, ifelse(
  is_unique(LEVEL5ID) |
    (is_unique(LEVEL4ID) & LEVEL5ID == 0) |
    (is_unique(LEVEL3ID) & LEVEL4ID == 0) |
    (is_unique(LEVEL2ID) & LEVEL3ID == 0) |
    (is_unique(LEVEL1ID) & LEVEL2ID == 0),
  "Yes", "No"
  )
)
```

If you need to generalize this up to an arbitrary number of levels, we could do that too, but writing it out seemed expedient for only 5 levels.